# Qt creator -1: error: [CMakeFiles/yahtzee.dir/gamecontroller.cpp.o] Error 1 : File not found

Tags: gcc, cmake, qt-creator, file-not-found

I am using Qt creator 2.5 with CMake (2.8.7) and gcc 4.6.3 and lately I have encountered this strange error :

> :-1: error: [CMakeFiles/yahtzee.dir/gamecontroller.cpp.o] Error 1
>   File not found

What can I do about it ? CMake is not generating this `gamecontroller.cpp.o`

this is my `CMakeLists.txt` file

```
project(cpp_workshop)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

# Set default compile flags for GCC
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    message(STATUS "GCC detected, adding compile flags")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror")
else()
    message(STATUS "GCC not detected, probably running Windows")
endif(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)


#add_definitions("-Wall -Werror")
ADD_DEFINITIONS("-Wno-unused-parameter")

add_executable(yahtzee #name of the executable
gamecontroller.h gamecontroller.cpp
player.h player.cpp
game.h game.cpp
dice.h dice.cpp
strategy.cpp strategy.h
istrategy.h
game_rules.h
main singleton 
)
```

And just to mention, all these files are located in directory and this is the 'build' directory that CMake creates :

```
CMakeCache.txt  CMakeFiles  cmake_install.cmake  cpp_workshop.cbp  Makefile
```

and the above `CMakeFiles` dir

```
CMakeCCompiler.cmake               CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake  CompilerIdCXX   TargetDirectories.txt
cmake.check_cache                  CMakeOutput.log                  Makefile2       yahtzee.dir
CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake             CMakeSystem.cmake                Makefile.cmake
CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin    CMakeTmp                         Progress
CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_CXX.bin  CompilerIdC                      progress.marks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was with `Cmake`'s argument passed to gcc

`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")`

I changed that to

`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")`

and now it works. Surprisingly, C++11 does not work with gcc yet ?

Comment: From 4.7 onwards, yes. But not for 4.6.x